# Performance of boxing and unboxing like technique for reference type variable?

Tags: c#, .net, boxing

Boxing and Unboxing are defined only for *value types*. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing):

> Boxing is the process of converting a ***value type*** to the type object or to any interface type implemented by this value type. When the CLR boxes a value type, it wraps the value inside a System.Object and stores it on the managed heap. Unboxing extracts the value type from the object. Boxing is implicit; unboxing is explicit. The concept of boxing and unboxing underlies the C# unified view of the type system in which a value of any type can be treated as an object.

Performance of Boxing and Unboxing is an expensive process, [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/performance-tips):

> Boxing and unboxing are computationally expensive processes. When a value type is boxed, an entirely new object must be created. This can take up to 20 times longer than a simple reference assignment. When unboxing, the casting process can take four times as long as an assignment.

Now, If I am using `string` and `string[]`, which are *reference types* and I do the following:

```
string A;
return (string)(object)A;
// IMP: Here first casting is similar to boxing (though for a reference type), and second casting is similar to unboxing.
```

Similarly,

```
string[] A;
return (string[])(object)A;
// IMP: Here first casting is similar to boxing (though for a reference type), and second casting is similar to unboxing.
```

Unlike value types which are computationally expensive here we are using reference types. Is there a similar performance impact in using boxing/unboxing like technique for reference type?

It looks similar to the following but none talk about performance impact (if any):

- [Object type boxing with a reference type variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092961/object-type-boxing-with-a-reference-type-variable),
- [What is boxing and unboxing and what are the trade offs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055/what-is-boxing-and-unboxing-and-what-are-the-trade-offs)
- [Will Boxing and Unboxing happen in Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371228/will-boxing-and-unboxing-happen-in-array)

Comment: Reference types don't get boxed.

Comment: @Glibus - [The truth about value types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/): "in the Microsoft implementation of C# on the desktop CLR, value types are stored on the stack when the value is a local variable or temporary that is not a closed-over local variable of a lambda or anonymous method, and the method body is not an iterator block, and the jitter chooses to not enregister the value." (Of course, this was written pre-`async`/`await` which would add another caveat to the above)

Comment: This is not about boxing but about casting. string => object is no cost, object => string may need runtime check (assuming it is not trivial for JIT to prove the type).

Comment: Your "Object type boxing with a reference type variable," link is broken.

Comment: @KennethK. Fixed. ~Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You may be interested to know that the C# compiler *completely removes* the `object` cast<sup>1</sup>. What you end up with is (assuming the method assigns a value to `A` from a constant and then has the code you've shown):

```
.method private hidebysig static string Thing() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldstr "fred"
    L_0005: castclass string
    L_000a: ret 
}
```

You may end up with a runtime check of the type of the reference here but I wouldn't be surprised if the JIT wasn't able to demonstrate statically that the reference on the stack due to `ldstr` was already `string` and so can remove any code that it might have considered generating for the `castclass` operation.

Reference casts are *assertions* (I know what type I'm dealing with better than the compiler). They're nothing like boxing and unboxing.

---

<sup>1</sup>As it will, in general, for any *upcast* between reference types.

Answer (score 1):

There will be no significant performance impact as strings are already reference types.