# Do strings get boxed in C#?

Tags: c#, string, value-type, boxing, reference-type

Update Jan 5, 2024: the answer at this link appears to show that the C# compiler completely removes the object cast when trying to cast a string to an object: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51381643/3163495

So, the answer is definitely no, strings do not get boxed.

---

**Original Question:**

I understand that value types like `int` or `bool` in C# get boxed, like in this example:

```
int i = 5;
object o = i; // boxing occurs
```

But do I need to worry about C# boxing `string` types as well?

```
string e = "hello world";
object o = e; // does boxing occur here?
```

I ask because `string` types are reference types with value semantics, so I'm unsure.

Comment: What's the question behind this question? String is a reference type but you can avoid boxing even with value types if you use generic parameters and containers instead of `object`

Comment: What is your source for the assertion that `System.String` has value semantics? Strings are immutable, but they do not have value semantics.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield The answer at this link and others to the same question say that strings have value semantics: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19838159/3163495

Comment: ^^ Which is just a fancy way of saying "strings are a little different". In the aspect you are concerned about, though you can view them as reference types.

Comment: Avoid using the `object` type in the first place, and then you don't worry about boxing so much.

Comment: *"But do I need to **worry** about C# boxing string types as well?"* This [smells like micro-optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/33843). No, boxing is usually not something you need to worry about, except in some very specific edge cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String is a reference type ([Strings and string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings) doc, [Built-in reference types: string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types#the-string-type) doc), boxing applies only to value types - [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing):

> Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type `object` or to any interface type implemented by this value type.

so no, they are not boxed when they are cast to `object`, it is so called [implicit reference conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#1028-implicit-reference-conversions):

> In other words, while a reference conversion can change the type of the reference, it never changes the type or value of the object being referred to.

So basically `string`'s are not boxed (or always boxed as soon as you create them - as correctly mentioned by [@Charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface) in the comments).

Answer (score 0):

That's not boxing at all. String is a reference type, only value types can be boxed. String already lives in heap.

`Object o = e` is upcasting since object is root for all type

Comment: Strictly speaking `System.Object` is the "root type" for value types too - check out the inheritance hierarchy of [`ValueType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype?view=net-7.0) - the base class for value types.

Answer (score -1):

Notwithstanding the "mental laziness" of some sources, strings do not have value semantics. Immutability and value equality are not the primary characteristics of value semantics.

Local values are allocated on the stack, not the heap. All instances of a value are the same size. On assignment, the actual value is copied. Strings do none of these things.

So, to say that they have value semantics is "fudging" the definition by quite a bit, leading to the kinds of uncertainty which your question presents.